# MVVM DataBinding

Tags: .net, wpf, user-interface, data-binding, mvvm

I have a ComboBox with the DataContext defined at application start to the appropriate ViewModel.  I want to grab items from a XML file but have user selections bind to the ViewModel, and ultimately the model.

XAML:

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="cbConnection"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource XmlConnectionList}, XPath=//ComboItem}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Key"
          SelectedValuePath="Value"
          SelectionChanged="{Binding Path=DataContext.cbConnection_SelectionChanged}"
          />
```

but I am getting the following exception at runtime:

`{"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeEventInfo' to type 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo'."}`

We know the ViewModel is appropriately set as the DataContext of the View's Window.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey Sammarcow... How did you get on? Did it work in the end?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are using;

```
SelectionChanged="{Binding Path=DataContext.cbConnection_SelectionChanged}"
```

Which is actually an event.

You should bind a Public Property (possibly implementing INotifyPropertyChanged) in your ViewModel to the **SelectedItem** Property to manage changes tn the Selection.

Assuming that your window has the DataContext, rather than the combobox itself...

**SelectedItem Binding Version:**

So your XAML would be something like;

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="cbConnection"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource XmlConnectionList}, XPath=//ComboItem}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Key"
          SelectedValuePath="Value"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.cbConnectionSelectedItem}"
/>
```

And in your ViewModel;

```cs
Private _cbConnectionSelectedItem As XmlElement

Public Property cbConnectionSelectedItem As XmlElement
     Get
         Return _cbConnectionSelectedItem
     End Get
     Set(value As XmlElement)
         If value.Equals(_cbConnectionSelectedItem) = False Then
             _cbConnectionSelectedItem = value
             OnPropertyChanged("cbConnectionSelectedItem")
            End If
     End Set
End Property
```

**Text Binding Version:**

Of course, if all your interested in is the Text Value of what they've chosen, you could in theory just bind the ComboBox Text Property to a Public String Property in your ViewModel;

Your XAML would then be;

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="cbConnection"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource XmlConnectionList}, XPath=//ComboItem}"
              DisplayMemberPath="Key"
              SelectedValuePath="Value"
              Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.cbConnectionText}"
    />
```

And your ViewModel;

```cs
Private _cbConnectionText As String

Public Property cbConnectionText As String
     Get
         Return _cbConnectionText
     End Get
     Set(value As String)
         If value.Equals(_cbConnectionText) = False Then
             _cbConnectionText = value
             OnPropertyChanged("cbConnectionText")
            End If
     End Set
End Property
```

**SelectedValue Binding Version:**

If you are displaying the Key, but want the Value from the Key/Value Pair, then you should bind to the SelectedValue;

XAML;

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="cbConnection" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource XmlConnectionList}, XPath=//ComboItem}"
    DisplayMemberPath="@Key" 
    SelectedValuePath="@Value" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=DataContext.cbConnectionValue}" />
```

ViewModel;

```cs
Private _cbConnectionValue As String

Public Property cbConnectionValue As String
     Get
         Return _cbConnectionValue
     End Get
     Set(value As String)
         If value.Equals(_cbConnectionText) = False Then
             _cbConnectionValue = value
             OnPropertyChanged("cbConnectionValue")
            End If
     End Set
End Property
```

Note the extra @ symbols.

As I mentioned above, this assumes that your Window has the DataContext set here. If not, then remove the "DataContext."'s from the Bindings above!

I assume you're seeing items listed in your ComboBox currently?

Hope this helps!

Comment: Binding to the SelectedIndex would require another reference to the XML data source within the ViewModel to determine the Value associated with the DisplayMEmeber, would it not?   Else I would only know the SelectedIndex because the ComboBox is populated from an external data source.

Comment: Hm, I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but `<ComboBox x:Name="cbConnection"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource XmlConnectionList}, XPath=//ComboItem}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Key"
                      SelectedValuePath="Value"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.ConnectionString}"
                      
                      />` does not seem to fire the getter or setter property ConnectionString within my ViewModel.

Comment: I've edited my original answer with some example code... It's in VB, but you should be able to convert to C# pretty easy if required ;-)

Comment: I could be wrong, but doesn't that binding resolve to a property path of DataContext.DataContext.ConnectionString? Try SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ConnectionString}"

Comment: Ahhhh... Yes indeed Wes, well spotted. If you are setting the DataContext of your ComboBox, rather than your window, then remove the "DataContext." from  the Bindings above!

Comment: @PGallagher  I am getting the the value System.Xml.XmlElement on binding.  I want the value from the Key/Value pair located within the "Value" XML Element of my external file.  "Key" is a friendly name for a server, "Value" is a connection string.

Comment: Hi Sammarcow... In this case it may be simplest to bind to the SelectedValue rather than SelectedItem or Text;

 <ComboBox x:Name="cbConnection"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource XmlConnectionList}, XPath=//ComboItem}"
              DisplayMemberPath="@Key"
              SelectedValuePath="@Value"
              SelectedValue="{Binding Path=DataContext.cbConnectionValue}"
    />

You'll then need a Public String Property in your VM to hook upto... Which will give you the Value... 

Hopefully that will sort it!

Comment: Brill! Not silly, typically there's alot of ways of achieving the same result... Seems like SelectedValue is the one for you!

Comment: Not directly relevant to the question, but your comment "Which is actually an event." prompted me to check my XAML, where I was trying to bind a boolean to the 'Checked' property of a CheckBox. 'Checked' is indeed an event! Bound it to IsChecked instead and all is well.

Answer (score 7):

you have to use event Triggers for comboBox Selection changed Event 
You should try below mention code

```
<ComboBox Margin="192,5,5,5" DisplayMemberPath="AttachmentName" ItemsSource="{Binding AttachementList, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource BasicComboBoxStyle}" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="DarkGray"
                          Name="cmb_AttchDetails" Width="287" Height="25" SelectedItem="{Binding Defaultrequiredattachment, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <l:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <l:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                            <l:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.AttachmentNameCommand,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:ChildWindow}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=cmb_AttchDetails,Path=SelectedItem}" />
                        </l:EventTrigger>
                    </l:Interaction.Triggers>
                </ComboBox>
```

for these you have to add reference like

```
  xmlns:l="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, but the accepted answer does seem to effectively achieve the same result.